# Selecting a record by comparing a column with a previous one

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to find people assigned to a profile of 99001, but only if they were previously assigned to a profile ending with a 0 (But not all zeros). The Current Profile will have an effictive date that matched the Expiration Date of the previous.

My code is not returning any records:

```
    SELECT p.personnum, 
    ap.name, 
    aa.effectivedtm,
    aa.expirationdtm
    FROM vp_employeev42 p,
    ASSIGNACCRUAL aa,  
    ACCRUALPROFILE ap
    WHERE p.personid=aa.employeeid
    and aa.ACCRUALPROFILEID= ap.ACCRUALPROFILEID
    and p.employmentstatus = 'Active'
    and p.ACCRUALPRFLNAME = '99001'
    and ap.name = '99001' 
    and aa.EFFECTIVEDTM = (
    select t2.expirationdtm from assignaccrual t2 
   where t2.employeeid = p.personid 
   and t2.accrualprofileid = ap.ACCRUALPROFILEID 
   and ap.NAME like '%0' 
   and ap.name != '00000')
   order by p.PERSONNUM, aa.EFFECTIVEDTM
```

Any help would be great.

ASSIGNACCRUAL-Sample

```
EMPLOYEEID  ACCRUALPROFILEID    EFFECTIVEDTM    EXPIRATIONDTM   UPDATEDBYUSRACCTID  UPDATEDTM   VERSIONCNT
3778    33482   1   1-Jan-53    1-Jan-00    -1  26-Mar-11   1
3779    33483   1   1-Jan-53    1-Jan-00    -1  26-Mar-11   1
403019  34285   1   1-Jan-53    1-Jan-14    -10 29-Dec-13   1
3781    33485   1   1-Jan-53    1-Jan-00    -1  26-Mar-11   1
3782    33486   1   1-Jan-53    1-Jan-00    -1  26-Mar-11   1
3783    33487   1   1-Jan-53    1-Jan-00    -1  26-Mar-11   1
3784    33488   1   1-Jan-53    1-Jan-00    -1  26-Mar-11   1
3785    33489   1   1-Jan-53    1-Jan-00    -1  26-Mar-11   1
3788    33492   1   1-Jan-53    1-Jan-00    -1  26-Mar-11   1
403021  65065   1   1-Jan-53    1-Jan-14    -10 29-Dec-13   1
3790    33494   1   1-Jan-53    1-Jan-00    -1  26-Mar-11   1
3792    33496   1   1-Jan-53    1-Jan-00    -1  26-Mar-11   1
403023  39566   1   1-Jan-53    1-Jan-14    -10 29-Dec-13   1
```

ACCRUALPROFILE-Sample

```
ACCRUALCODEID   ADVANCEDSW  NAME    VERSION
    1       0   Default 9
    202     0   4040    1
    203     0   4042    3
    2       0   0   3
    3       0   1010    10
    4       0   1011    5
    5       0   1012    3
    6       0   2000    4
    7       0   2001    3
    8       0   2010    4
```

If I remove the last 2 qualifiers this is what I would see.

```
1004719 Default 01-JAN-53   01-JAN-14
1004719 01010   01-JAN-14   28-JAN-14
1004719 99001   28-JAN-14   01-JAN-00
1005256 Default 01-JAN-53   01-JAN-14
1005256 02010   01-JAN-14   01-FEB-14
1005256 99001   01-FEB-14   01-JAN-00
1008323 Default 01-JAN-53   01-JAN-14
1008323 01010   01-JAN-14   07-FEB-14
1008323 99001   07-FEB-14   01-JAN-00
1014598 Default 01-JAN-53   01-JAN-14
1014598 02010   01-JAN-14   28-JAN-14
1014598 99001   28-JAN-14   01-JAN-00
1024852 Default 01-JAN-53   01-JAN-14
1024852 01010   01-JAN-14   28-JAN-14
```

Comment: take a a look at analytic functions.  You don't post enough information, like table schemas, and sample data, so not sure how much  help you will get w/o that.

Comment: As @OldProgrammer says - analytic functions, try connect by level or so.

Comment: I am really not well versed in Oracle.  I can figure out simple queries, but this one has me confused.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `lag()` function to get the previous name.  You need to do this in a subquery, so the `where` filtering conditions will not affect the definition of the previous record.

If I understand your query, then this should be what you need (or something close to it):

```
select personnum, name, effectivedtm, expirationdtm
from (SELECT p.personnum, ap.name, aa.effectivedtm, aa.expirationdtm,
             p.employementstatus, p.ACCRUALPRFLNAME, ap.name,
             lag(ap.name) over (partition by p.personnum order by aa.effectivedtm) as prevname
      FROM ASSIGNACCRUAL aa join 
           ACCRUALPROFILE ap
           on aa.ACCRUALPROFILEID = ap.ACCRUALPROFILEID join
           vp_employeev42 p
           on p.personid = aa.employeeid
     ) t
where employmentstatus = 'Active' and
      ACCRUALPRFLNAME = '99001' and
      name = '99001' and
      prevname like '%0' and
      prevname <> '00000'
order by PERSONNUM, EFFECTIVEDTM;
```